# Test the uniform convergence of the series in indicated region

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Test the uniform convergence of the series

I tried to find $M_n$ such that $|\sum_{n=1}^ \infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n-1}}{1-z^{2n-1}}|\le M_n $

**by using Abel's Theorem**

This is the question :

*Test the uniform convergence of the series*
$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n-1}}{1-z^{2n-1}}$$ where $|z|\lt 1$

Comment: A necessary condition for the uniform convergence of a series is that the terms of the series converge uniformly to $0$. Is that the case here?

Comment: could you explain this to me ? if you talk about the nth term
I see that the limit tense to 1 not to zero ?

Comment: For each fixed $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, you have $$\left\lvert \frac{z^{2n-1}}{1-z^{2n-1}}\right\rvert \to 0.$$ But for uniform convergence, you need that convergence to be uniform on $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, i.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \left\{\left\lvert \frac{z^{2n-1}}{1-z^{2n-1}}\right\rvert : \lvert z\rvert < 1\right\} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each fixed $z$ with $|z|<1,$ you have
$
\left|\frac{z^{2 n-1}}{1-z^{2 n-1}}\right| \rightarrow 0
$
But for uniform convergence, you need that convergence to be uniform on $|z|=1$, i.e.
$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \left\{\left|\frac{z^{2 n-1}}{1-z^{2 n-1}}\right|:|z|<1\right\}=0
$